# How to create Action Mode like Captain Android App?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionmode

I am very curious how to create Action mode like below image?is it made from custom layout?

[image]

Comment: your question is unclear.. i don't think the above screen shot is using an action bar as action bars usually contain your app name and icon.. please try to be make your question clearer,

Comment: @erik this  contextual action bar  is little bit different from normal one,there are two menus which have equal space. normally in cab , in Left Side - right mark menu to dismiss the action bar,Middle- Tittle,right side- menu what u add there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is custom layout in the `ActionBar`.

Roman Nurik wrote splendid sample for this. You can find it here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/developers/samples/android/+/master/ui/actionbar/DoneBar

Bottom line is  you inflate a custom view in the `ActionBar`.